# Do I have a correct understanding of Margin of Error/Accepted Error involved in sampling - Conflicting Previous Answers

Tags: sampling, error, excel

I constructed a sample size calculator in Excel:

```
Response Rate * (1 - Response Rate) * [Norm.Inv((1-alpha)/2) * (-1)/Accepted Error]^2
```

If post sampling I have: **p = 25%** and **Accepted Error = +/- 2%**, does that mean that:

1. p=23%-27% or
2. p=24.5%-25.5%?

I know this has been covered, but since I found conflicting answers, I thought I would ask.

Comment: Can you link to the previous answers that conflict? Also, in what sense is this a sample size calculator? I don't see N anywhere, eg.

Comment: Might wanna read Agresti &Co.: Agresti, A. and Caffo, B. (2000). Simple and effective confidence intervals for proportions and differences of proportions result from adding two successes and two failures. *The American Statistician*, 54(4):280–288.  **Aslo:** Agresti, A. and Coull, B. A. (1998). Approximate is better than “exact” for interval estimation of binomial proportions. *The American Statistician*, 52(2):119–126.

Comment: You probably have a wrong understanding of the concept of response rate, which is the fraction of people in the sample who provided any response (vs. non-respondents from whom you heard nothing). See [Standard Definitions of the American Association for Public Opinion Research](http://www.aapor.org/AAPORKentico/Communications/AAPOR-Journals/Standard-Definitions.aspx).